# Location of IDEDistribution.standard.log?

Tags: xcode, ipa, ad-hoc-distribution

While exporting `Ad-Hoc` ipa, I found an error,

> IPA processing failed

What is the location of the `IDEDistribution.standard.log` look into for detail logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I get that error, I also get a button that says "Show Logs".  Clicking on that button brings me to "/private/var/folders/[several gibberish folders]/[projectname]_[timestamp].xcdistributionlogs/".  This folder contains several logs, including `IDEDistribution.standard.log`.